# Differential Equation: Solve $y''-4y'+3y=4e^x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For this question it has an initial condition of $y(0)=5$ and $y'(0)=3$.

I managed to get $y = Ae^x + Be^{3x} - 2xe^x$. Solving for $A$ and $B$ I would get $A = 7$ and $B = -2$. However, the real solution is $(5-2x)e^x$. I have no idea how they got rid of the power of $e^{3x}$ and subtracted those $2$ together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Moo: If those are your equations, then $a = 13/2$ and $b=-3/2$ are their solution.

Comment: Oops, transcribed them wrong, that should have been $a + b = 5, a + 3 b - 2 = 3 \implies a = 5, b = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The initial conditions read:

$$ A\cdot e^0 + B\cdot e^0 - 0 = 5\\
A\cdot e^0 + 3B\cdot e^0 -2\cdot e^0 = 3
$$
From which $$A+B=5\\A+3B-2 = 3$$ and from there $A=5$ and $B=0$. To get to the answer you can use the distributive law to pull out a factor of $e^x$.

Your mistake appears to have been an error in taking the derivative of the $-2xe^x$ at $x=0$.